# How create Part not restorable in e4 application

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, e4

In e3 to create not restorable View I set field "restorable" to false in extension  `org.eclipse.ui.views` and it works. In my e4 application I create PartDescriptor with tag "NoRestore" but it do nothing. After restart Part is shown. What I do wrong? Or it is bug?

Answer (score 2):

If you let e4 save the workbench model on exit it is restored exactly as saved the next time the RCP is started. There is no support for a `NoRestore` tag.

Specifying the `-clearPersistedState` flag on startup will reset the model to the initial state. You can also specify `-persistState false` to stop the model being saved on exit.

If you just want to deal with one part you can alter the model in your life cycle class during startup. Something like:

```java
@ProcessAdditions
public void processAdditions(MApplication app, EModelService modelService)
{
  MUIElement el = modelService.find("your part id", app);
  if (el != null) {
    el.setToBeRendered(false);
  }
}
```

which just finds a part and turns off the 'to be rendered' flag.

Comment: Thanks. For what purposes is the `IPresentationEngine.NO_RESTORE` constant created? Or it will be used in future?

Comment: There is no `NO_RESTORE` constant in the Eclipse 4.7.2 `IPresentationEngine` - what version of Eclipse are you using?

Comment: I fetch from git version 1.6 of `org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench` and find this tag in it. But in my Eclipse 4.7.2 version is 1.5.... I jump in future)) Sorry for your time.

Comment: And one more question! If my part description placed in fragment, how I can do that? Outside of E4LifeCycle? Addon is useful for this purposes?

Comment: @ProcessAdditions runs after the fragments have been merged in to the model so this is OK.

Comment: I think an AddOn will probably work also, but haven't tested that,

Answer (score 1):

For compatibility with future versions, in which the `IPresentationEngine.NO_RESTORE`("NoRestore") tag will be present, you can use the following code.

```
@PreSave
void preSave(MApplication a_app, EModelService a_modelService){

    ArrayList<MElementContainer<MUIElement>> containers = new ArrayList<>();
    List<MPart> parts = a_modelService.findElements(a_app, null, MPart.class, Arrays.asList("NoRestore"));
    parts.forEach(p -> {
        p.setToBeRendered(false); // hide parts 
        containers.add(p.getParent()); // collect containers with no restorable parts
    });
    // hide containers which contains only no restorable parts
    containers.stream().filter(c -> c.getChildren().stream().allMatch(ch -> ch.getTags().contains("NoRestore"))).forEach(c -> c.setToBeRendered(false));
}
```

NOTE. Attempts to add the same code to methods with annotations `@ProcessAdditions` or `@ProcessRemovals` did not help: errors occurred and after the restart of the application no parts were displayed. So I added my code to the `@PreSave` method.

Comment: if you don't want the "hidden" parts to clutter your workbench.xmi, you better also remove them from your parent `p.getParent().getChildren().remove(p);`